# How to copy a specific files based on first letter in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I have some sort of files (55 files). Every file has unique name. So I have to copy the files which are starting from letter `a`  to another location. I need to know how to select files by starting letter `a` & copy them into another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [globbing](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/glob.7.html)

```
cp path/to/source_folder/a* /path/to/target_folder
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @yunzen .That is so much helpful to my studies.